# How do I validate the Javascript Code in ACE editor?

Tags: ace-editor, codemirror

I want to prepare a site similar to `Datacamp` or `Codeacademy` for our students. I made lots of research on code editors and now I use `ACE editor`. I can operate the `ACE editor` input but now I need some guidance how to validate and run the code which I text and run.

Until now I have solution to run my code:

```
<form> 
    <div id="editor" style="height: 100px; width: 100px"> </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="editor" style="display: none;">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var $editor = $('#editor');
        if ($editor.length > 0) {
            var editor = ace.edit('editor');
            editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/css");
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
            var input = $('input[name="editor"]');
                editor.getSession().on("change", function () {
                input.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
                console.log(input.val(editor.getSession().getValue()));
                $editor.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
            });

        }
    });
</script>
```

When I type `"2+3"`, I see console result:

```
2
2+
2+3
```

What I want is to get the result of the arithmetic operator which is "5".
How can I make it work and If it possible to run `Python` code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To tun python code you need to either send it to server and evaluate it there or use something like https://github.com/replit/jsrepl